# Null Pointer Exception EditText - Android

Tags: android, dialog, nullpointerexception, android-edittext

I am trying to prompt a user with a dialog box which contains two EditText boxs, a positive and negative button. The problem I am getting is a null pointer exception when trying to retrieve the value from the EditText boxs. Here is my code,

```
            LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(context);
            layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            builder.setTitle("New Location");
            builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_location_dialog, null)); 

            final EditText titleBox = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.title);
            final EditText descriptionBox = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.description);             

            builder.setPositiveButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int button) {

                    String title = titleBox.getText().toString();
                    String description = descriptionBox.getText().toString();
                    Log.d("User Setting title / description to: ", title + " : " + description);

                    //Add new Point to Map
                    addGeoPointToMap(mapOverlays,longpressLocation,title, description);    

                    return;
                }
            });

            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    Log.d("Cancel setting Title & adding point","");
                    return;
                }
            });
            builder.show();
```

If anybody could give me a hand I would appreciate it! Also, bonus marks if somebody can explain what the best convention for handleing multiple dialog boxs throughout an app is.

Comment: Can you check if titleBox is null on the very first line of `onClick()`?   Also check if they are null after you call `findViewById()`. Maybe try removing the `final`s.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not referencing the EditText objects correctly.

do the following and it will work:

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_location_dialog, null);
builder.setView(v); 

//here is your mistake:

final EditText titleBox = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.title);
final EditText descriptionBox = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.description);
```

Comment: @Tom celic : just mark the answer as correct if you find he solution for future reference